# Jest Test cases are failing for nodejs controller

Tags: node.js, jestjs

When I am declaring a controller in node js like below all test cases are running fine.

```
 module.exports = (req,res) => {
    //code here 
  }
```

I am accessing the above controller like below in my test case file:

```
    const controller = require('filename')
    controller(req,res);
```

However, when I am declaring the same controller in node js like below all the test cases are getting failed.

```
const getController = (req,res) => {
//Code here 
}
module.exports = { getController }
```

I am accessing the above controller like below in my test case file:

```
const {getController } = require('filename');
getController (req,res);
```

Can someone please tell me what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your syntax is wrong.

Use:

```
module.exports = { getController : getController }
```

and use it in 2 ways:

1. `import {getController} from 'filename';`
2. `const getController = require('filename').getController`

When you use `require`, you require a module, not a function of a module. When you use `import`, you are importing functions from a module.

You can read [here](https://www.educba.com/require-vs-import/) about the differences between `require` and `import`